# Multiple Select for simple adapter in listactivity

Tags: android

How do i enable multiple select for simple adapter list ?
i did this

```
list=this.getListView();
list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

But i am still not able to multi select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [this](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-multiple-choice-example/) will help you in creating multiple choice mode listview.

I am guessing that you are setting list to "multiple choice" after it has been already created.

If you still face any problem, post your exact code.

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: No, i am using ListActvity with SimpleAdapter so instead of this android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice i have my own layout , to this list i wanted to make it multi selectable

Comment: Please post your whole code, it will be better to understand the problem then !!